# Error XF001: Xamarin.Forms targets have been imported multiple times. Please check your project file and remove the duplicate import(s)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

But I have not duplicate imports in my projects.

Comment: I confirm that this sometimes happens with xamarin.android. A project is working fine; then one day, without any change by the programmer to the project settings or references or imports, this problem starts occuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to 
`Analyze -> Code Cleanup -> Run Code Cleanup on Solution`  close the project.  delete `obj` and `bin` folders in the solution and reopen then check

Comment: Skip the first sentence: "Code Cleanup" cannot possibly help: what that does is make your source code match any *style* settings you have; it has zero effect on the compiled result of a project.

Comment: Sometimes this can be fixed simply by quitting and restarting Visual Studio. Next try Rebuild Solution. If still a problem, then do what this answer says (close project; delete obj and bin folders; reopen project; try to build again).

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this error from time to time on UWP and have not been able to get a satisfactory answer about why it happens. I can sometimes get around it by doing a clean then build, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I hit this and wrestled with it for over an hour. Made clean, clean all, manually deleted all the bin and obj directories. Still the same. Out of desperation, I cloned the project into another directory. The new, clean checkout builds fine.